# PhoneGap write to file

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new to PhoneGap and trying to develop a simple application to write to a textfile. I've used the documentation of PhoneGap which uses LocalFileSystem.

```
// Cordova is loading
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); // PhoneGap is fully loaded

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady()
{
    //alert('Hello');
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function fail(){
    console.log('fail');
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    var path = "test.txt";
    fileSystem.root.getFile(path, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
      writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
      console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
      writer.truncate(11);  
      writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
      console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
      writer.seek(4);
      writer.write(" different text");
      writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
      console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
      }
      };
     };
writer.write("some sample text");
}
```

When running this code I got an Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined at
Using other Javascript gives me the same error on other objects (e.g. ActiveXObject...)

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the features in /res/xml/config.xml:

```
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
```

And also the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The ActiveXObject only exists in Internet Explorer.